# On/Off switch for a sealed underwater container

Tags: latching-relay, reed-switch

I know this can be done, I just can't put my finger on exactly how to wire it up. I have an underwater housing that I seal up indoors and take out on a boat. The device inside needs to be turned on before putting the housing in the water and turned off when we retrieve the housing maintaining the seal. The device has runs at no more than 18V DC and relatively low amperage (2A max).

I have seen other devices that use a two reed switches and a magnet on the outside of the housing to accomplish this, but I'm not sure of the mechanism that keeps the device powered on after the "On" reed switch is triggered. I am currently looking at a dual coil latching relay that I think will accomplish what I'm trying to do. I've tried to illustrate this with MS Paint in red. I think each reed switch needs to be in their own circuit with the battery (its just poorly drawn here).
[image: Backup Battery Sketch with on/off reed switches]

My questions are:

1. Am I on the right track with the idea about the dual coil latching
   relay?
2. Is there an easier way to accomplish this goal without a relay?

Comment: Just search for an IP68-rated switch. The most common type is a rocker switch, since it is the easiest to fit a waterproof membrane over the actuator.

Comment: @jayben Thanks for the suggestion. The device is rated to go to 300m and I can't punch any holes in the hull of the pressure vessel itself. I don't think a rocker switch will be applicable here.

Comment: @jayben IP68 simply means "customized product for underwater use". It doesn't mean anything else, nor does it specify a certain depth or water pressure. That is, product x and product y could both have IP68 but only product x works for a particular application. A cheap sports watch and a nuclear submarine both have IP68.

Comment: Wifi motorized switch

Comment: @Bolli How do you route power to the "device inside"?  What material is the waterproof housing made of?

Comment: Dual-coil relay is certainly a way to do it. I bet most people use transistor circuits but if you are more familiar with relays you can use a relay.

Comment: @Bolli The reed switch and magnet is the first thing that came to mind before you even mentioned it. Clearly, it must be "obvious" to everyone. I'm not sure why you don't want to use it. (Walls too thick? Iron used exclusively for the box?) You could just use mercury in a bistable situation (upside down glass u-tube for example) where you rotate the box a bit to move the mercury from one side to the other. That's bistable if the box doesn't undergo rotation in the water. More details probably needed to explore imaginative ideas, though. Bistable relays, if you can set them outside the box.

Comment: @periblepsis I actually do want to use the reed switches. The housing is aluminum and I don't think its too thick for a magnet, but I haven't explored that entirely yet. It's the relay that I'm unsure about how to go about using or how to narrow down the list in selecting one. About the bistable mercury, I can almost guarantee the pressure vessel will rotate during deployment

Comment: @user253751 thanks for that suggestion. I'll look more into transistor circuits for this function. I am completely open to both at this point and am just looking for a cost and energy efficient solution.

Comment: @Bolli It's VERY cheap to just try out the magnet+reed relay ampule. Just get a sheet of the aluminum with the thickness you expect to use, physically tape the glass reed relay ampule to one side of it, hook up an ohmmeter to the two leads, and apply various types of magnets to the other side in various orientations. I'd start with the highest power magnets to begin with, just to make sure. If those have a problem then the idea is not going to work. Orientation and magnet shape ***matter***. But there are lots of ideas shown in the datasheets I've seen. So there is help.

Comment: @Buck8pe Inside of the pressure vessel there is the device (a transponder), a main battery (18v) and the backup battery (probably 14v) that I am working on integrating. The entire pressure vessel is a cylinder made of milled aluminum about 1/4" thick.

Comment: besides cost and size, another reason transistors may be preferable to relays is that relays are vulnerable to mechanical shocks.

Comment: if you just search this site for 'latching power switch' you should find many circuits with various properties, that use non-latching normally-open push-buttons as power switches. (Some use the same button for on/off, some use two separate buttons, some turn off automatically after a time, some don't, some require the button to be held down for a time, etc). Reed switches can substitute these buttons.